# Getting an error while saving hidden type data in mongodb database using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs

I have got two things in form the first is add a password and the other is id which is no need to enter as it comes from the database directly when I click on add I got an error

Post method is

```
router.post('/', checkLogin, function (req, res, next) {
    var user = localStorage.getItem('loginname');

    var add_model = new pass_cat({
        password: req.body.catename,
        user_id: req.body.id
    })
    add_model.save(function (err, doc) {
        if (err) throw err;

        res.render('AddCategory', {
            title: 'Password Management System',
            user: user,
            msg: 'Inserted Successfully'
        })
    })

});
```

And the ejs code for the form is

```
<form action="/add_category" id="EmployeeForm" class="form-horizontal" method="post"  role="form">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%= data%>" >
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="Username" class="col-md-3 control-label">Add Category Name</label>
   <div class="col-md-9">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="catename" placeholder="Enter Password Category">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="User_id" class="col-md-3 control-label">User_id</label>
   <div class="col-md-9">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userid" value="<%=data[0]._id%>" placeholder="Enter Password Category">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you also add the error in the question description?

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%= data%>" >
there is no need of this line in the form,
as data you are not setting anywhere, and its value is not defined.

Comment: @VishwadeepKapoor Through your comment my problem would not solved but i was getting the idea to do it ,ThankYou so much

Comment: thanks @Rajatsharma converting comment to answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%= data%>" >
```

there is no need of this line in the form, as data you are not setting anywhere, and its value is not defined.